# Disable telephone control (answer call, call) from Bluetooth headphones

Tags: bluetooth, media-button

Is there a way to disable telephone control (answer call, call) from Bluetooth headphones? I just want to listen to music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Setting - Bluetooth and find your headphone device in the list and press the settings gear next to it. Uncheck Phone Audio or similar entries related to phone/telephone (may vary by Android version or OEM).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, Accessibility, Answering and ending calls. Turn off the setting that automatically connects when you have headphones in.